# How does garbage collection works in operating systems?

Tags: operating-systems

[image: file_system_structure_example]

As per the author,

> ...In this case, we generally need to use a garbage collection scheme to determine when the last reference has been deleted and the disk space can be reallocated. Garbage collection involves traversing the entire file system, marking everything that can be accessed. Then, a second pass collects everything that is not marked onto a list of free space...

[image: marked_accessible_or_not]

Is this how it works? i.e we don't mark a file which is pointing to itself as accessible and thus delete it later on.

Comment: operating system concepts by galvin et al